# Swift: Saving button image in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to save button image inside button view. Here is briefly what my code looks like:

I have a `UITableView` with button in it. Whenever I press the button the image changes. I change the image using this code:

First I use:

```
cell.checkmarkButton.addTarget(self, action:
        #selector(subscribeTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to recognize when the image is tapped. Then I use:

```
@objc func subscribeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    selectedButton = String(sender.tag)

    if let ButtonImage = sender.image(for: .normal),
        let Image = UIImage(named: "WhiteCheckMarkButton"),
        ButtonImage.pngData() == Image.pngData()
    {
        sender.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "GreenCheckMarkButton"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "WhiteCheckMarkButton"), for: .normal)
    }
```

Inside my `subscribeTapped` function to change the image. All good it changes the image but I can't seem to find out how to save once the image has changed. It seems really confusing to me. I can definitely do it if the image is not in a tableView using UserDefaults. But inside a tableView I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: What do you mean by save? Could you please clarify the finer details of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so by save I mean whenever I click the button it changes its image so whenever I exit and enter the application I want to see the changed Image in the tableview cell.

Comment: You can still use UserDefaults to keep track of the button image and you can re-load the button image based on UserDefaults in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thanks Jack can you please give me more information because I will have 168 buttons and I don't think it's efficient to save the button state one by one.